# Can COVID-19 be transferred through food handled by infected individuals?

Tags: covid-19, food-safety, disease-transmission, disinfection

Do COVID-19 spread by consuming foods that have been handled by infected individuals?

My question is related to foods such as bread that we can't really clean up before eating being handled by infected individuals.

How can we disinfect these foods?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: For bread, you could microwave them